# Websocket via Apache/Varnish failed

Tags: javascript, apache, websocket, varnish, ratchet

I've been trying to get this connection to the websocket to work for days now, but I still end up getting an error when trying to connect to it via Javascript.

The error the javascript throws is below:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://lmc-staging.mydomain.org:8081/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
brainsocket.min.js:1 Event {clipboardData: undefined, path: NodeList[0], cancelBubble: false, returnValue: true, srcElement: WebSocket…}bubbles: false cancelBubble: false cancelable: false clipboardData: undefined currentTarget: WebSocket defaultPrevented: false eventPhase: 0path: NodeList[0] returnValue: true srcElement: WebSockettarget: WebSockettimeStamp: 1421938720697 type: "error"__proto__: Event

brainsocket.min.js:1 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

The request is `piped` using Varnish to an Apache webserver (xxx.xxx.xxx.203). The varnish config is posted below:

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 

# Internal hosts; same as purge, but separated for clarity.
acl internal {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.0"/24;
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.203";
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.204";
}

# Hosts allowed to purge cache
acl purge {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.0"/24;
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.203";
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.204";
}

# DEV webserver
backend vsrv1474 {
  .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.203";
  .port = "80";
  .connect_timeout = 300s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}

# DEV brainsocket
backend brainsocket {
  .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.203";
  .port = "8081";
  .connect_timeout = 300s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}

# PROD webserver
backend vsrv1475 {
  .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.204";
  .port = "80";
  #.connect_timeout = 5s;
  #.first_byte_timeout = 60s;a
  #.between_bytes_timeout = 60s;
  .connect_timeout = 300s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}


sub vcl_recv {
  # Allow purge from hosts in purge acl or return 405
  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
      error 405 "Not allowed";
    }
    return(lookup);
  }


# entry for brainsocket
  if (req.http.Upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
    set req.backend = brainsocket;
    return (pipe);
  }

# end entry for brainsocket

  if (req.url ~ "/dev/" || req.http.host == "staging.mydomain.org" || req.http.host == "dev.mydomain2.org" || req.http.host == "lmc-staging.mydomain.org" ){
    set req.backend = vsrv1474;
    return(pass);
  } elsif ( req.http.host == "www.mydomain2.org" || req.http.host == "lmc.mydomain2.org" ) {
    set req.backend = vsrv1475;
  } else {
    set req.backend = vsrv1475;
  }


  if (req.url ~ "^/misc/progress\.js\?[0-9]+$") {
    set req.url = "/misc/progress.js";
  }

  if (req.url ~ "^/admin/content/backup_migrate/export") {
    return (pipe);
  }

  # Do not cache these paths.
  if(req.url ~ "^/status\.php$"||
      req.url ~ "^/update\.php$"||
      req.url ~ "^/install\.php" ||
      req.url ~ "^/admin" ||
      req.url ~ "^/admin/.*$"||
      req.url ~ "^/user" ||
      req.url ~ "^/user/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/users/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/info/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/flag/.*$"||
      req.url ~ "^.*/ajax/.*$"||
      req.url ~ "^.*/facebook-rss.xml$" ||
      req.url ~ "^.*/twitter-rss.xml$" ||
      req.url ~ "^.*/ahah/.*$") {
      return(pass);
  }

  # Disallow outside access to cron.php or install.php
  if (req.url ~ "^/(cron|install)\.php$" && !client.ip ~ internal) {
    error 404 "Page not found.";
  }

  # Always cache the following file types for all users.
  if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js|html|htm|woff)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }

  # Remove all cookies that Drupal doesn't need to know about. ANY remaining
  # cookie will cause the request to pass-through to Apache. For the most part
  # we always set the NO_CACHE cookie after any POST request, disabling the
  # Varnish cache temporarily. The session cookie allows all authenticated users
  # to pass through as long as they're logged in.
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(S{1,2}ESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE|CI_SESSION|ci_session|token|PHPSESSID)=", "; \1=");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

    if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
      # If there are no remaining cookies, remove the cookie header. If there
      # aren't any cookie headers, Varnish's default behavior will be to cache
      # the page.
      unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    else {
      # If there is any cookies left (a session or NO_CACHE cookie), do not
      # cache the page. Pass it on to Apache directly.
      return (pass);
    }
  }


  # Remove the "has_js" cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the "Drupal.toolbar.collapsed" cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "Drupal.toolbar.collapsed=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
  if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
  }

  # Cache static content unique to the theme (so no user uploaded images)
  if (req.url ~ "^/themes/" && req.url ~ ".(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g)") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
  }

}


sub vcl_pipe {
    #copy the upgrade header
    if (req.http.upgrade) {
        set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
    }

    #closing the connection might be necessary for some applications as the connection will remain open forever and consume resources if not properly stopped by server or client
    #set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}


sub vcl_miss {
  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    purge;
    error 200 "Purged";
  }
}

sub vcl_hit {
  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    purge;
    error 200 "Purged";
  }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
  unset beresp.http.Vary;
  set beresp.http.x-url = req.url;
  set beresp.http.x-host = req.http.host;

 # Don't allow static files to set cookies.
  if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js|html|htm)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$") {
    # beresp == Back-end response from the web server.
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }

  # Check if no ttl and a cookie set. 
  if (beresp.ttl <= 0s && beresp.http.Cookie ~ ".+" ) {
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable: No ttl; has cookie";
  # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
  } elsif (beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable: No ttl; no cookie";
  # You don't wish to cache content for logged in users
  } elsif (req.http.Cookie ~ "(S{1,2}ESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE|CI_SESSION|ci_session|token|PHPSESSID)") {
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Session";
    return(hit_for_pass);

    # You are respecting the Cache-Control=private header from the backend
  } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
    return(hit_for_pass);

  # Varnish determined the object was cacheable
  } else {
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
  }

  return(deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }
  unset resp.http.x-url; # Optional
  unset resp.http.x-host; # Optional
  unset resp.http.Server;
  unset resp.http.X-Generator;
  unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
  unset resp.http.X-Drupal-Cache;
}
```

I am using the brainsocket package, which allows you to create client and server side sockets using Laravel. Brainsocket uses Ratchet as its underlying websocket layer.

Comment: is varnish listening on port 8081? your brainsocket is, but unclear if varnish is also configured for that.

Comment: Is there an easy way for testing this? I looked at the wireshark traffic and it seemed as though the traffic was being relayed to another IP from the varnish server, but then it broke off. I'll update my question with a screenshot from Wireshark.

Comment: check out /etc/default/varnish which port is defined. or run "netstat -an | grep 8081 | grep -i listen" on the varnish machine

Comment: Does varnish pipe all incoming headers by default?  I've ran into issues with web sockets and "proxy"-style request forwarding before, where crucial websocket-specific headers went missing by the time they arrived at the backend.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was (as Marcel Dumont suggested) related to the fact that Varnish was not configured to listen on port 8081. So we redirected the frontend client to connect on port 80 and relied on Varnish to pipe the information on through to the underlying websocket on port 8081.